# JavaScript - Is it necessary to check for condtion first

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is necessary to check for the condition in this particular example.

The condition I'm talking about is `if ( Id.indexOf("_") )`.

It just checks to see if `Id` has an underscore and if so then set the variable to strip the underscore and replace with hyphen.

I know I can just use `Id = Id.split("_").join("-");` without the if statement checking to see if the condition is true, but just wondering if in this case is it good practice to check for the condition first or not?

Which way would you do it? And explain why please.

```
    Id = "My_ID";
    var brand = "The Brand";        
    var b = brand.trim().toLowerCase();
    var page = b.split(/\W+/g).join("-");

    if ( Id.indexOf("_") ) {
      Id = Id.split("_").join("-");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no underscore your `split()` won't do anything, so no - there's no need for the `if` here. Go with something like that and you're fine:

```
Id = Id.split("_").join("-");
```

or

```
Id = Id.replace(/_/g, '-');
```

to avoid creating an array first.

Answer (score 2):

This could answer your question:

```
console.log("mytext".split("_").join("-"));  // mytext
console.log("my_text".split("_").join("-")); // my-text
```

furthermore condition in your code `if (Id.indexOf("_"))` does not work as you intended. You need to use `if (Id.indexOf("_") > -1)` or `(~Id.indexOf("_"))`